# Validate jwt token inbound webservice

Tags: authentication, auth-provider

We have a requirement to validate jwt tokens for inbound webservices:

- In Salesforce we will expose some REST WS
- 3rd party system will call salesforce with a jwt token* in the Authorization header

*jwt token already requested following the oauth2 flow from an external idp server.

Any guidance how to do that in Salesforce without changing the flow?

Comment: Are you using Oauth2 JWT Flow? if yes then why do you need explicit validation? it will validate the token when you send it to the rest end point?. Is the jwt token provided by salesforce or external IDP?

Comment: The External Idp is providing the JWT Token

Answer (score 0):

You want [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) . In this flow you will exchange the JWT token for oAuth access token. You can then use the access token in Authorization header to call your REST API.

Comment: The token is provided by external IDP but this oauth flow is for salesforce to exchange JWT for token will that work?

Comment: @RedDevil If the JWT token conforms to SF requirements, then yes. Depends on the IdP capabilities.

Comment: What is meant by JWT Token conform to SFDC requirement?

Comment: @AkramG See the SF doc linked in my answer